# mysql get error 1064 when i try to prepare from

Tags: mysql

I trying to find lastday table and export to another folder, code is:

```
select @lastday := date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day);
    SET @datanewname = '_m2_raw_Data';
    SELECT @datalasttablename:=concat(@lastday,@datanewname);
    set @path = ' into outfile ''C:\\Db\\test.csv''' ;
    set @field = ' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '',''' ;
    set @enclosed = ' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ''"''' ;
    set @lines = ' LINES TERMINATED BY ''\\n''';
    set @select = ' select * from';
    select @query:=concat(@select,@datalasttablename,@path,@field,@enclosed,@lines);
    select @query;
    prepare a from @query;
```

the result of select @query is :

```
 select * from2017-11-12_m2_raw_Data into outfile 'C:\Db\test.csv'
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED
 BY '\n'
```

but the error is comes with

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '@query' at line 1 0.000 sec

Answer (score 0):

This statement is invalid

```
prepare a @query;
```

This is what mysql expects

```
PREPARE stmt_name FROM preparable_stmt
```

Judging from what I can see, you might be wanting something like this:

```
PREPARE a FROM @query;
```

[Read more about preparing statements here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html)

Comment: Sorry I missed the from, I typed in workbench it still give me same errors